# Chart.js minBarLength work for stacked bars?

Tags: chart.js

We are working with chart.js stacked bar charts and running into an issue when a month with a small amount of data is next to a month with a lot of data.

We're using the chartjs-plugin-datalabels plugin so we can show the values inside the stacked bars. However, if the range is high, bars with small values have their text squeezed to an unreadable amount.

We have currently tried adding the minBarLength attribute to all datasets, but it apparently only seems to affect the bottom-most stacked bar.

```
    minBarLength: 30
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/jsh961cn/1/

If minBarLength doesn't work, is there some workaround to explicitly set the height of each stacked bar, even though the y-axis numbers would no longer make sense?